Simple way to see if $n$-qubit Hamiltonian has no interaction terms?
Consider a system of $n$-qubits. The Hilbert space is $\mathcal{H} \cong \mathbb{C}^2 \otimes ... \otimes \mathbb{C}^2$. Fix each tensor factor $\mathbb{C}^2$ to have the $\sigma_z$ vector space basis $\{\lvert + z \rangle, \lvert -z \rangle\}.$
Consider an arbitrary traceless Hamiltonian $\mathfrak{su}(2^n) \ni H: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$. In general,
$$H = \sum_i c_i X_i$$
where $\{X_i\}$ is a basis of the underlying vector space of $\mathfrak{su}(2^n)$.
In this setting, define a no-interaction Hamiltonian to be an $H \in \mathfrak{su}(2^n)$ such that $H$ is a sum of $n$-tensor products where only one of the $n$ tensor factors is not the identity. For example,
$$\sigma_z \otimes \mathbb{I} \otimes \mathbb{I}$$
is a permissible term to build a no-interaction Hamiltonian for a $3$-qubit system.
Is there a simple way to check if a $H \in \mathfrak{su}(2^n)$ is a no-interaction Hamiltonian?

Note: I know that I can use the Hilbert-Schmidt norm
$$\langle A,B\rangle_{HS} \equiv \frac{1}{\dim\mathcal{H}}\text{Tr}(A^\dagger B)$$
to project $H$ into the no-interaction sector of the space of traceless Hermitian matrices, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way.

Well. You could take the partial traces of $H$ and then check if $H=h_1 \otimes I\otimes I\ldots + I\otimes h_2 \otimes I\ldots + \ldots$. This should work for arbitrary (say, finite) systems. Here I assume that with non-interacting you mean the RHS of my latter equation, for some (hermitian) operators $h_j$. (the procedure is silly, I think, but OK, it is a possible "solution"). Note: The partial trace of $H$ with respect to the first tensor factor is, in the non-interacting case, something like $h_1+I+I+I+\ldots$, so you could extract $h_1$ easily.

Is there a way of saying “no-interaction “ in a basis independent way? Also depends on what you mean by simple. Does using a computer count?
